# Which the fastest way to compose multiple images into one by ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I have 10+ png files, 2000x1500px.

Which the fastest way to compose these images into one?

I use ImageMagick and make it so:

```
composite -gravity center 1.png 2.png final.png 
composite -gravity center 3.png final.png final.png
composite -gravity center 4.png final.png final.png
composite -gravity center 5.png final.png final.png
composite -gravity center 6.png final.png final.png
composite -gravity center 7.png final.png final.png
composite -gravity center 8.png final.png final.png
composite -gravity center 9.png final.png final.png
composite -gravity center 10s.png final.png final.png
composite -gravity center 11.png final.png final.png
```

On my local machine it takes near 10 sec.
How can i make it faster? Is it possible?
Regards!

Comment: No images or expected results? Try `magick -gravity center 1.png 2.png -composite 3.png -composite 4.png -composite ... result.png` Replace `magick` with `convert` if still using v6.

Comment: The final image is created, all good, but I want it to be faster than 10 seconds.

Comment: Ok, but you still haven't provided images, so I have no idea how big they are, nor whether you are running on a RaspberryPi or a 5GHz 64-core monster, nor have you said how long it actually takes...

Comment: Images dimensions - 2000x1500px, size - from 50kb to 500kb. Processor - 3,5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5.

Comment: To see if the PNG decoding (reading) is slowing you down, try making a *"Magick Pixel Cache"* version of each of your input files like this `convert 1.png 1.mpc` and then time just the compositing alone using `convert 1.mpc 2.mpc -composite 3.mpc -composite ...` and see if that is faster. If so, we'll parallelize MPC creation.

Comment: Then try changing the output file type to JPEG (temporarily) to see if PNG encoding (writing) is slowing you down.

Comment: You didn't say if my initial, single command was faster than your 10-11 separate `composite` commands either...

Comment: PNG encoding is slow... Time to switch to WebP if your toolchain supports it (your client browsers all do by now).

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes, your one line command is more faster!!! it takes 1-2 sec. Thank you very much!